# Composer SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: php, ssl, composer-php

I'm trying to install a new package from composer using `composer require` but then an error was showed

```
existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

send of 95 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy
https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://packagist.org/p/jenssegers/date%24a796b298222b37954ea0f488a5b99d057114dda34ecead922188b0abf832faba.json
  " file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

Here's the result of `composer diagnose`

```
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: WARNING
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
Checking https connectivity to packagist: WARNING
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

send of 95 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy
Checking HTTP proxy: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

send of 95 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy
Checking HTTP proxy support for request_fulluri: WARNING
Unable to assess the situation, maybe packagist.org is down (The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! )
Checking HTTPS proxy support for request_fulluri: WARNING
Unable to assess the situation, maybe github is down (The "https://api.github.com/repos/Seldaek/jsonlint/zipball/1.0.0" file could not be downloaded: SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

send of 96 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy)
Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://api.github.com/rate_limit" file could not be downloaded: SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

send of 96 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: <somekey>
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: <somekey>
OK
Checking composer version:

  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL: An existing connection was forcibly close
  d by the remote host.
  send of 97 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
  failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy


diagnose
```

I am not using any proxy. I've tried `composer self-update`. I've tried to search for other solution but can't find the right one. please help!